# Ruby Thread Pool pausing on ThreadError.queue _empty

Tags: ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I am attempting to write a script that runs over subdirectories and analyze contents. I am using threadpool, which has dramatically improved performance. However, my script is pausing near completion, due to ThreadError -> empty queue errors, which hang the program for close to a minute. I cant seem to ignore the errors and continue the process. The current code:

```rb
children = Dir.children(MEDIA_FOLDER)

Thread.report_on_exception = false
Thread.abort_on_exception = false

jobs = Queue.new
children.each { |i| jobs.push i }

workers = 8.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    begin
      while (x = jobs.pop(true))
        check_subdirectory(x)
      end
    rescue Exception => error
      # handle error so it doesnt hang
      puts error
    end
  end
end

workers.map(&:join)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your script seems to use a thread pool to process a queue of jobs, where each job represents a child directory under `MEDIA_FOLDER`.
It is supposed to spawn eight threads to process these jobs concurrently. Each thread repeatedly tries to pop a job from the queue and processes it. When the queue is empty, a `ThreadError` is raised, which seems to pause the script near its completion.

Instead of using `rescue` and dealing with `ThreadError` (note: [never rescue `Exception`](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-exception-vs-standarderror-whats-the-difference/)), you might consider using instead a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to signal the end of jobs to the threads.

```
+------------------------------------------+
|   Script Execution                       |
|                                          |
|   +------------+   +-----------+         |
|   | Thread 1   |   |  Thread 2 |         |
|   +------------+   +-----------+         |
|   | jobs Queue |                         |
|   +------------+                         |
|   | Sentinel   |                         |
|   +------------+                         |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Your code would be:

```rb
children = Dir.children(MEDIA_FOLDER)

Thread.report_on_exception = false
Thread.abort_on_exception = false

jobs = Queue.new
children.each { |i| jobs.push i }
# Push a sentinel value to signal the end of jobs
8.times { jobs.push nil }

workers = 8.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      x = jobs.pop
      break if x.nil?  # break if sentinel value is encountered
      check_subdirectory(x)
    rescue => error  # catch other exceptions
      puts error
    end
  end
end

workers.map(&:join)
```

A sentinel value (`nil`) is pushed into the [queue](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Thread/Queue.html) for each worker [thread](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Thread.html). That way, when a thread pops a `nil`, it knows there are no more jobs to process and exits the loop.
The `rescue` block is adjusted to capture any unexpected exceptions, logging them to the console. That way, if an unexpected error occurs, it will not be masked, and you will be able to see it in the console output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to raise an exception here, just use `jobs.pop` and `close` the queue *(`deq` is alias for `pop`)*:

> when `empty?` is true, `deq(false)` will not suspend the thread and will return `nil`.

*https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/thread/queue#method-i-close*

For example:

```rb
jobs = Thread::Queue.new

10.times do |i|
  jobs << i
  puts "#{i} produced"
end

workers = 4.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    while value = jobs.pop
      sleep rand(2)
      puts "consumed #{value}"
    end
  end
end

jobs.close
workers.map(&:join)

# =>
# 0 produced
# 1 produced
# 2 produced
# 3 produced
# 4 produced
# 5 produced
# 6 produced
# 7 produced
# 8 produced
# 9 produced
# consumed 2
# consumed 3
# consumed 4
# consumed 5
# consumed 6
# consumed 8
# consumed 9
# consumed 0
# consumed 1
# consumed 7
```